# How to get a story changelist using Rally python API?

Tags: python, rally, pyral

How to get the list of changes made to a Story or Defect in Rally?

`for r in rally.get('User Story', fetch=True, query=""):
    print r.Changesets`

`r.Changesets` seems to always be an empty collection.

I also tried the `rally.get('Revision'...)` approach which seems to return me lots and lots of revisions but they do not contain any reference to the object (story/defect/...) being modified.

Also tried to use the `query="ObjectID = %s" % r.FormattedID` but this always returns nothing.

I also opened a bug on https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForPython/issues/29 but I am not sure if this will get any attention soon enough.

Answer (score 2):

Changeset object, which is a collection of Change objects in [WS API](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/) is not related to revisions. Those objects are intended for integration with version control systems, e.g. Git, GitHub, Mercurial, Subversion connectors, etc, and have no meaning outside of integration context.

It is possible to traverse from an artifact, e.g. a user story to its revisions using the endpoints below. For example a user story query (FormattedID = US123) :

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/hierarchicalrequirement?query=(FormattedID%20%3D%20US123)&fetch=true
```

will include a reference to RevisionHistory object, redacted for brevity

```
RevisionHistory: 
{
_ref: "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/revisionhistory/19382984273", 
_type: "RevisionHistory"
},
```

This endpoint:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/revisionhistory/19382984273
```

returns Revision history object that has a referene to Revisions collection

```
{
RevisionHistory: 
{
_ref: "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/revisionhistory/19382984273", 
_objectVersion: "3",
CreationDate: "2014-05-29T15:23:21.491Z",
ObjectID: 19382984273,
Revisions: 
{
_ref: "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/RevisionHistory/19382984273/Revisions", 
_type: "Revision",
Count: 5
}
}
}
```

Here is an example of Revisions endpoint with narrowed fetch

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/RevisionHistory/19382984273/Revisions?fetch=RevisionNumber,User,Description,CreationDate
```

Generally revision history queries are expensive and we do not recommend using them except in narrow scenarios.

v2.0 removed the ability to return child collections in the same response for performance reasons. Per [WS API documentation](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/rest_collections.jsp) fetching a collection will return an object with the count and the url from which to get the collection data. To get full objects a separate request is needed.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599988/how-to-query-for-state-transitions) that mentioned LookbackAPI. [LBAPI](https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/doc/#/manual) allows to get historic data.
There is no built-in support for LookbackAPI in pyral or any other Rally toolkits except [AppSDK2](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/#!/api/Rally.data.lookback.SnapshotStore) but LBAPI is language agnostic.

Comment: I spend quite a few good hours trying to get the revisions out. I need this to migrate some data and parsing Description does not sound good as an approach. I am trying to use the lookback API but it does not return any Revisions. See https://gist.github.com/ssbarnea/bcce8a825f243f8c6c34 this returns 0 revisions for each queried object, even if I do see the revisions in the UI.

Comment: I agree that parsing revisons descripton is not a good approach, that's why we have LookbackAPI. LBAPI manual is an interactive document where you can test your queries before writing code. There are also examples of using LBAPI endpoints on StackOverflow. Test your queries directly in the browser first, and see if it returns snapshots. In your example you are using both ScheduleState and State when your query object is hierarchicalrequirement. User story does not have State, only ScheduleState.